# Unable to take the user to Google Pay screen with TapAndPay

Tags: android, kotlin, google-pay

I'm trying to integrate Google Pay SDK in a project. For achieving this goal, I need to generate an object and pass it to a built in method. After that, SDK is responsible to take the user to Google Pay screen, but the google pay screen does not pop up. Here is the code I've written:

```
  val userAddress = UserAddress.newBuilder()
                .setName(it.userAddress.name)
                .setAddress1(it.userAddress.address1)
                .setLocality(it.userAddress.locality)
                .setAdministrativeArea(it.userAddress.administrativeArea)
                .setCountryCode(it.userAddress.countryCode)
                .setPostalCode(it.userAddress.postalCode)
                .setPhoneNumber(it.userAddress.phoneNumber)
                .build()
            val pushTokenizeRequest = PushTokenizeRequest.Builder()
                .setOpaquePaymentCard(it.opcBase64.toByteArray())
                .setNetwork(it.cardNetwork.ordinal)
                .setTokenServiceProvider(it.tokenProvider.ordinal)
                .setDisplayName(it.userAddress.name)
                .setLastDigits(it.lastDigits)
                .setUserAddress(userAddress)
                .build()

            tapAndPayClient.pushTokenize(
                this, pushTokenizeRequest, 1
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue then after reviewing the docs a couple of times found that the google pay team provides a form to be submitted first in order to use the SDK or methods of SDK , The main fields inside the form required are

package name
SHA-256 fingerprint key
Company name
Environment mode

since the google provisioning SDK is not available publicly as it's private so one has to fill out the form the google pay team will review in two business days and then you will be able to call any kind of method related to this SDK only from your app, like its something giving your app permission to use this SDK[image]

https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/allowlist